# Android app/intent to add text metadata to a picture

Tags: android, images, metadata-editor, exif, camera

After I take a picture with my Android's phone camera, I would like to add a short description, for instance *"bday gift from Sarah"* or *"caponata lunch at La Ciccia"*.

What's the fastest way to do this?

Requirements:

- Fast to use
- Doable directly from the camera app without too many steps
- Metadata is contained within the JPG file. For instance appended to the filename or added to EXIF if there is a field for that. Metadata should not be stored separately, because I move pictures files around on PC.
- Must work offline
- Free (ads OK), ideally open source

Answer (score 1):

I'm not around an android right now so I can't test/confirm details but... I believe that [PhotoEdit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iudesk.android.photo.editor)
will do that with a work flow like this:

1. Default Camera Share function
2. Photo Editor
3. Save
4. Modify Exif Data
5. (enter text)
6. hit OK
7. Say yes to Overwrite prompt

Add the metadata as proper EXIF data so yes contained in the file.

In regards to the free requirement... *somewhat*; advertisement supported free version or premium with no ads.

Comment: +1 That works indeed! It is not fast to use though, loading the whole graphical edition interface even though I don't need it, and many steps to go through. Ads are OK.

Comment: yes definitely not an *ideal* workflow but I figured I'd mention it since it had been a few days with no other real answers

Answer (score 0):

Low-tech solution:

I use the `Gallery rename plugin` app.

1. Share the picture to Gallery Rename
2. Suffix the picture with any description I want to add.

Unfortunately it does not seem to be on Google Play anymore, I just copy the APK preciously from phone to phone. Some shady mirrors seem to have it, if anyone find a trustable source please share it, thanks!